# How to pass data on listview click dynamically to another activity

Tags: java, android

On the first actvity I am using following activity

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, Dashboard_Description__page.class);
            intent.putExtra("key",str_bookmarkfile);
            startActivity(intent);
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        }
    });
```

In the second activity am using

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
        System.out.println(data);
```

I am getting error. If i am using  "hello" in place of str_bookmarkfile
then it gives hello at output. How to make dynamic above code

Comment: What is str_bookmarkfile?

Comment: By dynamically, do you mean to pass either string or integer or float or any type?

Comment: this is str_bookmarkfile  is a string which is used in listview

Comment: Check if str_bookmarkfile is null.

Comment: no this is not null.  i am able to see in list view

Comment: show  full code adapter please

Comment: show you adapter so that we can tell how to make it dynamically @pawankumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way you can pass data one activity to another:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, Dashboard_Description__page.class);
            intent.putExtra("key",YOUR_STRING);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

and retrive String in another activity.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String s = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: it means your string value is null.@pawankumar

Comment: string is not null.  i am able to see on list view

Comment: just try to log your string and put condition like if (!YourString.equals(null)){ }

Comment: intent.putExtra("key","i want ot pass dynmic varibale here which is use in list view:);

Comment: intent.putExtra("Key","Value"); this way you can pass string.@pawankumar

Comment: Just pass your String object instead of "Value" @pawankumar

Comment: what do u mean by this. Can you please clarify more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106702/discussion-between-pawan-kumar-and-rushdroid).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String some = intent.getStringExtra("key");
   System.out.println(some );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is seems correct but check your manifest

```
ls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, Dashboard_Description__page.class);
        intent.putExtra("key","Hello");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

in other side retrive String in second activity. and make sure your bundle not null

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String s = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

### **If you want this flow to be dynamic..**

..then you can't hardcode what's being passed to your second activity.

By "hardcode", I mean this:

> intent.putExtra("key", str_bookmarkfile);

The `String` you're using to populate the `ListView` must come from somewhere, right? Be it a `List<String>` or perhaps a `String[]`. You should use this data, coupled with the position of click the `ListView` gave you to find out which `String` you should send to your second activity.

How? Let's look at your `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, Dashboard_Description__page.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", str_bookmarkfile);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

See the parameters that you'll be getting there; especially this: `int position`. What it does is it gives you the information about which item just got clicked in your ListView by *its position*.

Now that you got this information, use it to actually get the data from your source likewise:

- If you're using a `List<String>` then use `yourListOfString.get(position)`
- ..or if you're using a `String[]` then use `yourArrayOfString[position]`

Those two calls will give you the data; *and this time it will be dynamic*. Because the data you'll be getting will depend on the position of the ListView item being clicked.

So your `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` should look a lot like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, Dashboard_Description__page.class);

    intent.putExtra("key", yourListOfString.get(position)); // ..if you're using List<String>
    intent.putExtra("key", yourArrayOfString[position]); Ç// ..if you're using String[].

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Hope this could clear things out for you! :)